# Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes1" to "uint256"

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solidity-0.5.x

Just tried to convert `byte` to `uint` using Solidity 0.5.x:

```
uint length = uint(arr[i]);
```

and got:

```
MyCode.sol:88:29: TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes1" to "uint256".
       uint length = uint(arr[i]);
                          ^----^
```

Answer (score 16):

The shortest solution I discovered after several tries:

```
uint length = uint(uint8(arr[i]));
```